# Issue regarding variable alteration in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code...

```
@organisims.each do |organisim|

  randomvalue = rand(10)
  prediction = organisim.predict

  if prediction == randomvalue
    organisim.resources += 1
  end
  if prediction != randomvalue
    organisim.resources -= 1
  end 
end
```

I am trying to alter the 'organisims' resources if the prediction it makes matches the randomly generated number. It seems to work fine, -1 if no match, +1 if there is a match.

The problem is that when I iterate this array (of organisims), processing their resources, I recieve duplicates in my output, such as

Cycle 100
Average resouces: 1500

Cycle 101
Average resouces: 1500

Then again,

Cycle 102
Average resouces: 1400

Cycle 103
Average resouces: 1400

Is this an issue with my code (I see no issues with it) or with the psudorandom number generator that Ruby uses?

Cheers as always
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be an issue of the scope of your accumulator consider this example.

```
# example Organism class
class Organisim

  attr_accessor :predict, :resources, :prediction

  def initialize
    @resources = 0
  end

  def predict
    @prediction = rand(10)
    @prediction
  end

end

# initialize @organisims
@organisims = []

100.times do
  @organisims << Organisim.new
end

puts "!!!! Starting Organisim Specific Run"
# iterate over array tracking organisim's resource
@organisims.each_with_index do |org, i|
  # parrallel assignment
  r, p = rand(10), org.predict
  #ruby ternery operator
  (p == r) ? org.resources += 1 : org.resources -= 1
  puts "Run #{i} Prediction: #{org.prediction} Instance Resources: #{org.resources} Overall Resources: n/a"
end

puts "!!!! Cumulative Resource Run"
# resources scoped outside the iteration loop as accumulator
overall_resources = 0

# re-initialize @organisims
@organisims = []

100.times do
  @organisims << Organisim.new
end

@organisims.each_with_index do |org, i|
  # parrallel assignment
  r, p = rand(10), org.predict
  #ruby ternery operator
  #track class level resource
  (p == r) ? org.resources += 1 : org.resources -= 1

  #iterate accumulator
  (p == r) ? overall_resources += 1 : overall_resources -= 1
  puts "Run #{i} Prediction: #{org.prediction} Instance Resources: #{org.resources} Overall Resources: #{overall_resources}"
end
```

The first iteration loop is like (I think) the one that you have in your question but you're changing the resource within the organisim object instance.

The second iteration your accumulator is outside the scope of your iteration so it grows and shrinks as the objects are acted upon. :-)